# mitmproxy: SSL keys not decrypting in Wireshark

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark, mitmproxy

And I'm not sure why.

mitmproxy installed with pip on Kali Linux.

Run using `$ SSLKEYLOGFILE="$PWD/.mitmproxy/sslkeylogfile.txt" mitmproxy` as per https://docs.mitmproxy.org/master/howto-wireshark-tls/

Firefox using FoxyProxy with proxy to 127.0.0.1:8080. Certificate installed.

Wireshark configured to use sslkeylogfile.txt also as per above docs.

And then go.

mitmproxy sees traffic:
[image: mitmproxy]

SSL key log file adds keys:
[image: sslkeylogfile]

And Wireshark captures traffic, but nothing is decrypted:
[image: wireshark]

As would be expected with successful SSL key usage https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/wireshark-tutorial-decrypting-https-traffic/

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The Wireshark screenshot shows TLS1.3 connections. Therefore you are likely affected by [this issue](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3994).

Comment: Thanks Robert. How do I disable TLS1.3 in Firefox? I changed security.tls.version.max to 3 in Firefox (4 is TLS1.3, 3 is 1.2) but I'm still getting 1.3 traffic (confirmed by ssllabs.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MitmProxy has at the moment an open [issue](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3994) that prevents writing a correct `SSLKEYLOGFILE` when TLS 1.3 is used.

Therefore my recommendation would be to disable TLS 1.3 for connections from client to MitmProxy and for connections from MitmProxy to the server. This can be done using the following command-line options:

```
--set ssl_version_server=TLSv1, TLSv1_1, TLSv1_2
--set ssl_version_client=TLSv1, TLSv1_1, TLSv1_2
```

See also MitmProxy documentation: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-options/

Edit: According to the comments in the issue the problem with TLS1.3 should be solved since Mitmproxy version v6.0.0 (released Dec 13, 2020).

Comment: Thanks Robert! I seem to get an error when I use multiple keys, so I had to simply use TLSv1_2. TLSv1 and TLSv1_1 were rejected by remote servers so they refused to connect.

Also, for anyone else looking, I found it easier to export the config file (`mitmproxy --optons > ~/.mitmproxy/config.yaml`) then edit it directly. For some reason there was no default config file in the directory.